# How to write output results to a CSV file

Tags: python-2.7, csv, image-processing, export-to-csv, gdal

I am writing a python code to get GDAL statistics (min, max, stddev, rows, col, bands etc.,). I could get all of those mentioned but how can i get the BitDepth of the input image and also how can i write all these stats into a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

CSV stands for "Comma Separated Values". This file only contains values and commas between them, so in order to write your data into a CSV file just create a file with the extension .csv and write your data with a comma after each value. To create a new line in the file just write `\n` to it.

This [link](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex16.html) might help with the writing operation to the file.

Comment: Thank You, I got it !  Any Idea how i can find the Bitdepth of the input image ??